# Create .json in python and pass it to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I'm trying to pass a python dict as a JSON to JavaScript function. Here is the dict:

```
dataset = {
'labels': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
'datasets': [{
'label': "test1",
'backgroundColor': "#54FFD820",
'borderColor': "#54FFD820",
'borderWidth': 2,
'hoverBackgroundColor': "#54FFD820",
'hoverBorderColor': "#54FFD820",
'data': [49, 47, 51, 48, 45, 44, 40, 42, 47, 45],
},
{
'label': "test2",
'backgroundColor': "#54FFD840",
'borderColor': "#54FFD840",
'borderWidth': 2,
'hoverBackgroundColor': "#54FFD840",
'hoverBorderColor': "#54FFD840",
'data': [11, 9, 7, 10, 9, 12, 16, 15, 18, 22],
},
{
'label': "test3",
'backgroundColor': "#54FFD860",
'borderColor': "#54FFD860",
'borderWidth': 2,
'hoverBackgroundColor': "#54FFD860",
'hoverBorderColor': "#54FFD860",
'data': [32, 35, 33, 31, 29, 34, 35, 37, 36, 34],
}]}
```

That's the python dict, I pass it with the use of simple flask function:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    data ={'pools': pools, 'intervals': time_intervals, 'dataset': json.dumps(dataset)}
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

I call the JS function from html:

```
...
<body onload="plot_it({ data : 'dataset' })">
...
```

plot_it() is chart.js function:

```
function plot_it(chart_data) {
 Chart.Line('test_chart', {
 options: options,
 data: chart_data
});
}
```

The `plot_it()` is working, the chary is rendered (empty). I'm struggling to debug this properly but I suspect it may be the issue with different python/JS JSON construction as I get no errors. Any tips appreciated!

Comment: You're not passing the variable through. Try using `{{ data }}`. This is how jinja detects variables

Comment: I'm not a Flask programmer, but I suspect you don't need to call `JSON.stringify()` yourself. It should encode the entire `data` dictionary for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong syntax to access the `dataset` from the `data` variable.

Try using dot notation, and make sure your variable is between two curly braces `{{ variable }}`.

```
<body onload="plot_it({{ data.dataset }})">
...
```

Alternatively, you can also use the subscript syntax(`[]`).

```
<body onload="plot_it({{ data['dataset'] }})">
...
```